# Connect to Amazon S3 without Access-Key and Secret-Key from Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I cannot connect to Amazon S3 through the IAM role. I have been told that I cannot use the `secret-key` or the `access-key,` but I can't find any way to do it without this.

Actually what I have is this:

```
public class S3Config {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.accesskey}")
    private String awsId;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.secretkey}")
    private String awsKey;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.role}")
    private String roleArn;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.region}")
    private String region;

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    @Primary
    public AmazonS3Client s3client() {

        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("", "");

        AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                .withRegion(Regions.fromName(region))
                .build();

        AssumeRoleRequest assumeRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest().withRoleArn(roleArn).withDurationSeconds(3600)
                .withRoleSessionName("Test");
        AssumeRoleResult roleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(assumeRequest);

        Credentials sessionCredentials = roleResponse.getCredentials();

        BasicSessionCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
                sessionCredentials.getAccessKeyId(),
                sessionCredentials.getSecretAccessKey(),
                sessionCredentials.getSessionToken());

        AmazonS3Client s3ClientRole = (AmazonS3Client) AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
                .withRegion(Regions.fromName(region))
                .build();

        AmazonS3Client s3Client = s3ClientRole;

        return s3Client;
    }
}
```

If on the line where I create the `awsCreds` object, I fill it correctly with the values ​​I get from the `application.properties`, if it does everything correctly. But if I leave it empty I never get to execute the line `stsClient.assumeRole(assumeRequest);` and it gives me connection time out error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should follow this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-roles.html#default-provider-chain

It should follow you step bu step on resolving you problem.

Basically an IAM Role allows a specific "resource", such as an EC2 instance, to connect to the service and thus you configure your client to get temporary credentials just to "authenticate" and "authorize" it.

Comment: I checked it, I did it the same but it still doesn't access me

Comment: If you are using it locally on your machine it will never works like this, because your machine is not associated to the IAM role you created. There are some workarounds here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=172460 and https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=604424

Answer (score 0):

Without Credentials, where region would be in your application properties as example:

application.properties:

```
aws.s3.config.region=us-east-1
```

---

Your configuration class:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@Data
public class CloudAwsS3Config {

@Bean
public AmazonS3 getClient() {

    return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
          .withCredentials(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(false))
          .build();



  }

}
```

The Pom.xml dependency:

```
<!--  Amazon S3 SDK   -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.632</version>
</dependency>
```

Note... if you have access key and secret key, change this to:

```
@Bean
public AmazonS3 getClient() {
    BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(getAccessKey(), getSecretKey());


    return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .withRegion(getRegion())
            .build();

}
```

Note: Only in the same cluster will be available to access the AWS S3 without access key and secret key.